# How to debug what Windows Admin Center is doing?

Tags: logging, winrm, trace, debug, windows-admin-center

I'm having issues with Windows Admin Center and the user interface doesn't really help troubleshooting them; thus I'd like to have a closer look at what WAC is actually doing with the servers it manages.

I know WAC uses WinRM and Remote PowerShell to manage systems; is there any way to get a full trace of the commands it sends and the answers and/or errors it receives back?

Is it possible to get a log of the actual commands exchanged between WAC and the systems it manages?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a browser (Edge) with "Developer Tools" enabled to see the trace for the API calls between the WAC and underlying host / cluster it is managing.

Comment: That would be useless. The browser only talks with WAC's web interface, I need to know what WAC is telling to the remote servers in order to implement the user's instructions.